# Which samba user for gvfs-mount (12.04)

Tags: nautilus, samba, gvfs

I mounted some samba shares in ubuntu 12.04 using nautilus, by clicking the share under "network". I've googled, but i can't find anywhere how to:

1. Which remote samba user were my shares mounted by?
2. How can i "forget" the credentials i were using and authenticate again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i found the solution in https://superuser.com/questions/479806/how-to-reset-passwords-in-nautilus-ubuntu-12-04.

You can see there which credentials are actually used and remove them.